Is there a meaningful distinction between "generating" and "characterizing"?
If I have a set of elements S, I can "generate" more elements, for example, by taking the power set of that set, P(S). This is the set of all subsets of S. A more powerful way of thinking about it is the set of all possible functions from S to a two-element set 2. In that case, we can map the elements of 2 to a conceptual semantics of "include / exclude", so a subset (in which we include or exclude each member of a set) is more like a special case of mapping the elements of S to two elements. The elements of 2 can now be thought of as classifying elements of S, assigning a property, or something else.
From the perspective of category theory, it seems like we can knock out the need for the Axiom of Power if we instead say that we have a category with exponential objects.
We can consider all maps from S to a three-element set 3. Maybe this could have some very interesting interpretation akin to S -> 2, in which we wish to assign each element of S one of 3 possible states or conditions. But what is very intriguing is that this does not have an immediate analogue to the power set, probably because the "in"-relation is binary. Therefore, for a ternary relation on sets, maybe it could have its own form of a "3-power" operation, forming a new set as well, but that's hard for me to see clearly.
A very interesting map could be S -> S. This seems like a way of pairing elements, since every element in S gets associated with an element in S.
Another interesting point is that the set of functions from 2 -> S would be written S to the power of 2; conventionally, we associate this with S x S. So we have a link between products and exponents that I think is part of the universal property of exponents and related to currying.
The above is a digression.
I am pretty preoccupied with the question of if there is a valid dichotomy in formal systems between "generating" vs. "characterizing", or if this distinction is an illusion.
The case of "generating" seems more related to computational, maybe also constructive, ways of thinking. It requires a concept of "stages", akin to "states". (It almost seems like it conceives of "the total set generated at the limit" as a single thing that can be factored into moments in time).
The "characterizing" paradigm assumes a set exists which has closure under a certain operation (=endomorphism). That is, we can just state some set exists which is closed under the power set operation. In that case, we never "generate new elements", rather, the operation associates elements to each other.
Is it always deeper to take the characterizing point of view? Mathematically, when we think we are "generating" new elements, you could argue that given the way functions are defined, the elements we "generated" already logically existed.
What does this mean for inductive definitions? Do they confuse us, since they are actually endomorphisms?
I am very confused and have a lot more tangential questions about all this.

This is some context I'd like to add. I don't believe my question would be accepted on Math Stack Exchange, since it's open ended, conceptual and interpretive.
Testing vs Generating, Characteristic functions vs ??
Overview of Syntax-Semantics Duality

-1: This is a mathematical question rather than a philosophy one. You can try your question on Math.SE.

Anyway, here is a simple example that demonstrates the difference between describing an object by generating elements, and describing an object by a characterizing property: the additive group of rational numbers is generated by elements of the form 1/(n!), one for each nonnegative integer n, with relations given by letting n times 1/(n!) be equal to 1/((n-1)!). It is characterized, up to its isomorphism, by its being the injective hull of the additive group of integers. Description by generation yields explicit elements you can refer to; description by characterization often doesn't.

Description by generation is often useful for explicit calculation, while description by characterization is often useful for proving abstract theorems. Both have advantages. It is possible to think of description by generation (or more accurately, description by presentation, i.e., description by giving generators and relations) as a special case of description by characterization. For example, if I give you a group with generating set G and relation set R, then that group is characterized by its being the free group on G satisfying relations R. Not sure if this answers your questions.

One more comment, sorry for the comment flood. There is an interesting philosophical question buried in all of this. We are talking about different modes of description of mathematical objects. In both modes (description by presentation, and description by characterization), what we are doing fits nicely with the Russellian theory of definite descriptions, with the caveat that both modes often only succeed in pinning down reference up to isomorphism. It is trickier to see how to square these modes of description of mathematical objects with the Kripkean theory of reference.


Is there a meaningful distinction between "generating" and
"characterizing"?

Example
If I understand correctly, we can characterize or simply define, without any formal proof, the addition function on N as follows:

For all natural numbers x and y, x+y is a natural number.

For all natural numbers x, we have x+0 = x.

For all natural numbers x and y, we have x+(y+1) = (x+y)+1


Alternatively, using Peano's Axioms for the set of natural numbers, and the axioms of set theory to construct Cartesian products, arbitrary subsets and functions in general, we can generate or formally prove the existence and uniqueness of such a function.
